# Initializing a matrix using a list with a string in it

Tags: matrix, netlogo

Here is my code:

```
extensions [matrix]
..
sources-own[keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword4 extrinsic-fitness visits]
..
to setup
create-sources
ask source 0  [
    set keyword1 (matrix:from-row-list [["cat"][2]])
]
...
..
.
```

Now, when I click on SETUP and inspect "source 0", it shows the matrix to be initialized as the following:

```
{{matrix:  [ [ 0 ][ 2 ] ]}}
```

Try as I might, I cannot get it to accept the string "cat" in place of the "0" in the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it.

A matrix in Netlogo can only hold numbers. One needs to use a "list" instead.